# How to wrap tape/cloth around hollow handle?

Tags: modeling, shrinkwrap

Hi im new and have been searching around about wrapping cloth/rope/tape around object, but every tutorial or question ive found has been around a solid object and not between 2 object or a hollow one.

Edit: The other tutorials have been using ShrinkWrap, but when i use it it seems to be buggy with the hollow opening.

Here is what im trying to do:
[image]
Making Multiple rounds of tape around a hollow gun handle, and have the least amount of space between tape and gun handle.

Here is my reference photo:
[image]

Comment: I would just dupe the handle. plug its hole, and use that as a _Shrinkwrap_ target?

Comment: @RobinBetts Good idea, will try!

Answer (score 4):

I would try this with cloth modifier and sewing checked.

For my experiment i created a mesh circle, extended it and gave it some solidify modifier.

Then i doubled that and rotated a bit.

The two white obstacles need collision modifiers.

I increased quality steps up to 30 to get that result.

[image]

Comment: This seems like a fun way to do it, but with lack of experience with blender im struggling a bit to make it work. How exactly are you changing the size of the circle to make it fold around? How is the bands not falling down or flying away? How isnt the circle clipping trough the two white objects?

Comment: if you are patient...i can make a tutorial about that. Writing all the steps down will take more time than just making a tutorial about it.

Comment: Yeah it could be cool if you made a tutorial about it, but i have some questions. Is this very practical for detailed model editing? Example would be making an exact replica of the reference above, would it be more difficult with this method compared to another?

Comment: I have no idea how to make it another way ☺️ and i don’t know whether it is practical for model editing. It is possible that manual modeling is quicker than using cloth physics.

Comment: Yeah i might need to do it more manual for my final models for what i want to do, but physics are cool doe :)

Comment: @JustAHobbyGuyNoob If you want to find out more about cloth sewing in Blender there are some tutorials on Youtube which explain it in general. Of course the most complicated part is getting it to do exactly what you want it to do ;)

Comment: @JustAHobbyGuyNoob For example, here are two beginner videos explaining it: [Sewing cloth in 2.92](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9GDWKzf1mc) creating a dress and [Sewing cloth in 2.93](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4Xwo3ygaCM) creating pants. As far as I know the workflow should still be the same in 3.0

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thank you will look into it :)

Comment: I think cloth simulation is exactly the type of tool you want to use for high details. Shrinkwrapping generates simpler geometry (and generating simpler geometry is actually harder).